# datagrid scope for Rails 4 about group and order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datagrid, scope, group-by

I've been getting confused about the scope in rails 4 all day long.
I created a model named User with :uid and another model named Letter with :user_uid,:content and something like. And a user has many letters.
What I want to do is: list each user's latest letter which the letter's content is not null.
So,in my letters grids I wrote like this：

```
class Letters

  include Datagrid
  scope do
    User.joins(:letters).group(:uid)
           .select(
              "users.*,  MAX(letters.created_at) latest_letter, letters.content, letters.created_at"
            ).order("latest_letter desc").where("letters.content IS NOT NULL")   
  end

  filter(:created_at, :date, :range => true)

  column(:id)
  column(:content)
  column(:created_at) do |model|
    format(model.created_at) do
      l model.created_at.to_date, format: :short
    end
  end
end
```

But I found that the content of letter is not the latest. Anything wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in SQL query. The best way to show latest message content not an SQL level but in ruby level

```
class Grid
  scope do

    User.joins(:letters).group(:uid)
           .select(
              "users.*,  MAX(letters.created_at) latest_letter"
            ).order("latest_letter desc").where("letters.content IS NOT NULL")   

  end

  column(:id)
  column(:content) do |user|
    user.letters.order("created_at desc").first.content
  end
end
```

If you still want to find latest message in SQL, you would need to use nested SQL (no other way...)

```
select users.*, l.created_at, l.content 

from users left join letters l on 
  l.user_id =users.id and l.created_at = 
    (select max(l2.created_at) from letters l2 where l2.user_id = users.id ) 

where l.content is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the reason why my codes could not work properly. You are such a nice man. : )